# wal_level both hot_standby and logical

Tags: postgresql, replication, configuration, postgresql-9.6

I have a PostgreSQL setup with one master and three slaves. It's configured as streaming replication.

Now, I want to replicate only a few tables from the master server to an analytic server using [pglogical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/es/recursos/pglogical/). For this, we need to enable the logical `wal_level`. So how can I enable it without breaking the existing replication?

Answer (score 9):

This is what the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/runtime-config-wal.html) says about the topic:

> `wal_level` determines how much information is written to the WAL. The default value is `replica`, which writes enough data to support WAL archiving and replication, including running read-only queries on a standby server. `minimal` removes all logging except the information required to recover from a crash or immediate shutdown. Finally, `logical` adds information necessary to support logical decoding. Each level includes the information logged at all lower levels. This parameter can only be set at server start.

From the text it's not overly clear, but `logical` is the highest level of all, meaning it includes everything the `replica` level does.  That means you can safely set `wal_level` to `logical`, it won't break your existing replication.

Comment: Crystal Clear ! Thanks